# RollupError: Could not resolve "./pages/layout/Layout" from "src/index.tsx"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure

I clone this source from GitHub and deploy to azure cloud, but when I run cmd "azd up" it was shown the error as below.
Here are my code:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createHashRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { initializeIcons } from '@fluentui/react';

import './index.css';

import Layout from './pages/layout/Layout';
import Chat   from './pages/chat/Chat';

initializeIcons();

const router = createHashRouter([
    {
        path: "/",
        element: <Layout />,
        children: [
            {
                index: true,
                element: <Chat />
            },
            {
                path: "qa",
                lazy: () => import('./pages/oneshot/OneShot')
            },
            {
                path: "*",
                lazy: () => import('./pages/NoPage')
            }
        ]
    }
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
Could not resolve "./pages/layout/Layout" from "src/index.tsx"
file: D:\C#\OpenAI\OpenAICustomKB\app\frontend\src\index.tsx
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./pages/layout/Layout" from "src/index.tsx"
    at error (file:///D:/C%23/OpenAI/OpenAICustomKB/app/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2245:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///D:/C%23/OpenAI/OpenAICustomKB/app/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24650:24)
    at file:///D:/C%23/OpenAI/OpenAICustomKB/app/frontend/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24612:26
  (x) Failed: Packaging service backend

ERROR: failed packaging service 'backend': failed invoking event handlers for 'prepackage', 'prepackage' hook failed with exit code: '1', Path: 'C:\Users\locnso\AppData\Local\Temp\azd-prepackage-825251035.ps1'. : exit code: 1
```

[image]

I google it but I newbie in node.js so I don't know what does the error message mean?

Comment: can you please share the source that which you tried?

Comment: Hi @Loc Hguyen, Iam unable to see the source code in your question.

Comment: @SureshChikkam sr my bad. I edited this post, this is my first time I post in Stack

Comment: what was your operating system in cloud? Linux or windows?

Comment: have you tried deploying source code from github to app service via azure portal. Please check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/BUBRVDK.png).

Comment: Im not sure, I just follow guide to deploy to azure, when run cmd "azd run" I see this error. This error relative frontend source code which build in react nodejs.

Comment: Ok@Loc Nguyen, I will reproduce, and I will provide the clear steps but tell me in azure you want to deploy to app service(web app) only right?

Comment: @SureshChikkam yes, right. Im working with this project https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo/

Comment: May you try this project https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo/ if this error exist?

Comment: I had cloned your frontend application to my GitHub and worked. check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/2djyxXR.png).

Comment: @SureshChikkam I have fixed my issue. The reason is in my folder path contains special character like '#' so it cause this error, lol. Thanks for your enthusiastic help and I will note your guide. thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue had fixed. The reason is in my folder path contains special character '#' so it cause this error.

Answer (score 1):

> ERROR: failed packaging service 'backend': failed invoking event handlers for 'prepackage', 'prepackage' hook failed with exit code: '1', Path: 'C:\Users\locnso\AppData\Local\Temp\azd-prepackage-825251035.ps1'. : exit code: 1

- Mostly the error which you get is when the specified file or path does not exist or is not accessible then you will find this. check this link for more [info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1289995/azd-up-azd-package-error?page=1).

I had reproduced by deploying frontend application from GitHub to App service via Azure portal check the below steps.

- Login-in to azure portal and click on create app service give the specific details then after to the second section there will be the deployment there you need to specify your GitHub repository details as below.

[image]

- You can check the workflow before deploying by clicking on preview.

[image]

- Then click on create the application which is in github repository will be directly deployed into the app service.
- You can check the deployment status in the portal or directly in the GitHub actions.

**Deployment status:**

[image]

Also please check the [Failed prepackaging service](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-search-openai-demo/issues/112) for more information.